# MariaDB: How to execute Perl-script from sql-script?

Tags: perl, stored-procedures, mariadb, dbi

Is it possible to execute a Perl-script from a SQL-script? For example:

```
ALTER table ADD extract TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

CALL(perl-script)   -- will update table extract

(continue with sql)
```

My intention is the following: to extract from column `table.freetext` all patterns of interest and `UPDATE` column `extract`. All this happend with Perl which connects with MariaDB but the Perl script itself was started by the SQL-script (maybe within a stored procedure). For example:

`freetext`='oil abc oil def salt'

Perl extracts patterns 'oil|salt'

`UPDATE` within in Perl (DBI) gives `extract`='oil,salt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this isn't possible by default, since this would be a huge security risk.

Consider the follwing perl script:

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Path;
rmtree("/var/lib/mysql/data");
```

Since all processes on the server are executed under system user 'mysql' each account would have the possibility to execute arbitrary code and to delete your entire data directory.

A workaround might be to write a UDF (user defined function), however it is also insecure.

Comment: Thanks for this informativ answer. UDF is what in MySQL is called stored procedure?

Comment: No, UDF is abbreviation for user defined function. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-functions/